# Is there a way to recover the contents of the Absolute Layout library?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've deleted content of Absolute Layout library in NetBeans by mistake. Is there a way to recover the contents of this library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to the Help menu and select About.
2. Copy the path given for Userdir.
3. Close NetBeans.
4. Go to the path location, then navigate to config/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries
5. Look at the files in that directory.
6. You're looking for something named absolutelayout.xml_hidden. (If you're using windows, you may need to change the options to show file extensions.)
7. Delete it.
8. Restart NetBeans

Comment: I've found only absolutelayout.xml - so i deleted that, it worked thx